# Prolog: How to create a list of predicates?

Tags: prolog

```
d_edge(a, b, 5).
e_edge(a, c, 6).
f_edge(b, c, 8).

% I will have a list of rules for the graph point 
% from source to destination with weight. 
list2pair([T], [A,B], [(T,A,B)]).
list2pair([T1|Tt], [A1,A2|T], Result) :-
   list2pair(Tt, [A1|T], R1),
   append([(T1,A1,A2)], R1, Result).
```

I want to come up with the result like

```
[d_edge(a,b), f_edge(b,c)]
```

my 1st arg will be the list of names `[d_edge,f_edge]`
my 2nd arg will be the list of vertexes `[a,b,c]`.

My current code generates `[(d_edge,a,b),(f_edge,b,c)]`.

Whenever I try to update the predicate from `(T1,A1,A2)` to `T1(,A1,A2)`
I get an error saying that it is not valid predicate.

I understand why I am getting the error. But I couldn't find a way around it.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: `T1(,A1,A2)` is syntactically incorrect.

Here's how you could proceed using the built-in predicate [`(=..)/2` (a.k.a. "univ")](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002duniv.html):

```
list2pair([T], [A1,A2], [X]) :-
   X =.. [T,A1,A2].
list2pair([T1|Tt], [A1,A2|T], [X|Xs]) :-
   X =.. [T1,A1,A2],
   list2pair(Tt, [A2|T], Xs).
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- list2pair([d_edge,f_edge], [a,b,c], Xs).
Xs = [d_edge(a,b),f_edge(b,c)] ? ;               % expected result
no
```

Note that the above only "constructs" these compound terms—it does **not** ensure that suitable facts `d_edge/3`, `f_edge/3` etc really do exist.

Comment: W.r.t. a.k.a. "univ". This used to succeed for:  `univ(name(a1,a2),[[n,a,m,e],a1,a2]).`